Is there an up-to-date programming reference for qiskit?
Every example of code for qiskit that I've seen has one or more commands that don't work out of the box. Even the way to verify that qiskit is installed from qiskit.org failed. I've managed to either figure out or find the correct syntax in a lot of these cases but it is not without effort.  This is like my experience with MVC in C#. The commands for MVC 1.0 changed considerably with the next version making the reference books obsolete.  So my question: Is there a reference that is up-to-date for programming with qiskit?

Based on your other comment, is this API documentation what you're looking for? https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit

Not a full API reference, but I created this playlist going over the basics because I had the same issue you’re pointing out. There really isn’t a good a reference out there.
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhI5X1mNN8ghWTnnUjwjMXGosOJSeYTW4&si=mnSkQm68-2MRXHZT

When I started learning about qiskit, I first started from the comprehensive online documentation found here.
I would recommend you to start going through the section step-by-step, which means you start from the section called "Start" and then move on to next section "Build" followed by "Transpile", "Verify", and "Run". These sections describe in great detail all the ways on how you can write a code in qiskit and how you can transpile the code to match the attributes of the real quantum system that you want to run your code on.
If you need an even more detailed help with the function and classes in qiskit then you can look here in the API reference for qiskit, qiskit-ibm-runtime, and qiskit-ibm-runtim REST API.
If you prefer, you can look at all the tutorials on various topics found here.
Another good source to learn qiskit is their youtube channel and blog. On youtube, I would especially recommend the new series "Coding with Qiskit 1.x" which quickly goes through how to install and run qiskit code in the latest version qiskit 1.x.
Finally, when following these documentation and tutorials if you find a bug or a mistake you can always raise an issue on qiskit github page.
An important note: Do not mix qiskit version<=0.46 with qiskit version 1.x. The online documentation is very descriptive about how to upgrade to qiskit 1.x versions, so follow those instructions.

This is a great tutorial but not really what I would call a reference..  To me, a reference would list all the qiskit commands with descriptions, list all the classes with their functions.  The functions would have a list of the inputs and outputs with descriptions.  All the books I've seen for qiskit are a couple of years old.  Based on what I've found, they are probably not current.  Thanks for your response to my question.

I have added the links to the qiskit, qiskit-ibm-runtime, and the REST APIs for qiskit-ibm-runtime in the answer. Hope this helps!
